# Unknown Calendar: where does it come from?

Tags: macos, calendar

Within Calendar (6.0) on Mountain Lion, beside my own 12 calendars, I noticed a calendar named `Calendar`.

I didn't create it. All my calendars are coming from a recent migration
from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion.

Where does this `Calendar` come from?
Is this a `default` calendar automatically created by `Calendar` (the application)?

Through an export (under `ics` format) I discovered that it is empty.

I'd like to remove this abnormal `Calendar`. 
Does anyone know if this default calendar is necessary for one of the `Calendar` functions?

Comment: Let's pop in an OS and a version and I'll walk you through how to pick apart the data sources. Most likely "Calendar" is an exchange account with no actual calendars defined, but the steps vary widely between the various OS we support. (iOS 5 through soon 7 and the Mac equivalents)

Comment: → stuffe: what point in this simple question may be clarified?

Comment: I've reopened it, but with all the distinct questions, it looks like he may have been concerned with all sorts of guesses. Especially the part where you ask if you can proceed without creating any problem. Since that is so individual, who can really say if we feel you understand our potential answer (or if we really understand your question). I'd hate to be 80% certain what's happening but be wrong and have you take my advice only to lose a calendar without a backup.

Comment: → bmike: thank you. Understood. I wouldn't answer such a risky question myself ☺. I'll take the risk with my own backup and test accounts, and answer with a validation through reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the directories:

```
~/Library/Calendars/*.calendar
```

where all calendars are stored, the command:

```
grep string ~/Library/Calendars/*.calendar
```

let me identify among the 4 strings found, which one of these directories
was the one containing my `Calendar` ghost calendar:

```
    [...]
    <string>#0E61B9FF</string>
    <string>22228888-4444-6666-AFAF-AAFF00005555</string>
    <string>Calendar</string>
    <string>Local</string>
    [...]
```

From the date of modification of directory:

```
% ls -l 22228888-4444-6666-AFAF-AAFF00005555.calendar
drwx------  4 hal  hal  170 Sep 21 17:10 22228888-4444-6666-AFAF-AAFF00005555.calendar
%
```

I diagnosed that this `Calendar` was imported through my first
synchronisation from a new iPhone containing just its default calendar
named `Calendar`.

Even with all my calendars more fresh on my Mac, this unexistent default
`Calendar` was imported.

---

I removed it on my Mac and made one more synchronisation to get rid of it on my iPhone and my Mac.